# WPF: validation confirmed password

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation

I have 2 PasswordBoxes. I need to check are passwords equal. I don't want to write this condition into [].xaml.cs code, but i want to mark PasswordBox in red when passwords aren't equal.

Should i write special ValidationRule, some code in ViewModel or something else? Can anyone help me? Now the validation is written in the [].xaml.cs but i want to avoid it.

Comment: What is wrong with having the validation inside the xaml.cs?

Comment: I want to use more beautiful solution of this problem. I can't move validation inside the xaml.cs to another View without copying of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
<PasswordBox Name="tbPassword" />
<PasswordBox Name="tbPasswordConf" />
<PasswordValidator 
      Box1="{Binding ElementName=tbPassword}" 
      Box2="{Binding ElementName=tbPasswordConf}" />
```

Code (this code is not cover all cases):

```
public class PasswordValidator : FrameworkElement
 {
  static IDictionary<PasswordBox, Brush> _passwordBoxes = new Dictionary<PasswordBox, Brush>();

  public static readonly DependencyProperty Box1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Box1", typeof(PasswordBox), typeof(PasswordValidator), new PropertyMetadata(Box1Changed));
  public static readonly DependencyProperty Box2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Box2", typeof(PasswordBox), typeof(PasswordValidator), new PropertyMetadata(Box2Changed));

  public PasswordBox Box1
  {
   get { return (PasswordBox)GetValue(Box1Property); }
   set { SetValue(Box1Property, value); }
  }
  public PasswordBox Box2
  {
   get { return (PasswordBox)GetValue(Box2Property); }
   set { SetValue(Box2Property, value); }
  }

  private static void Box1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
  }
  private static void Box2Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
   var pv = (PasswordValidator)d;
   _passwordBoxes[pv.Box2] = pv.Box2.BorderBrush;
   pv.Box2.LostFocus += (obj, evt) =>
   {
    if (pv.Box1.Password != pv.Box2.Password)
    {
     pv.Box2.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
    else
    {
     pv.Box2.BorderBrush = _passwordBoxes[pv.Box2];
    }
   };
  }
 }
```

Also, it's possible to define dependency property with style of error and setting it instead of BorderBrush. But i don't know how to use in this case the standard ErrorTemplate.

Comment: You should probably make that more idiomatic by making that an Attached Property. Used like: `<PasswordBox x:Name="tbPasswordConf" PasswordValidator.ValidateAgainst="{Binding ElementName=tbPassword}" ... />`.

Comment: It's good proposal. I'll try it. Thanks. Do you know how can I use standard ErrorTemplate that used in ValidationRules instead of setting of BorderBrush?

Comment: Fwiw: I used this solution, with the addition of an `IsValid` property, so I can inform the ViewModel of any problems, and stop the Save operation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a readonly property in your viewModel and return a brush for the border of the PasswordConfirmBox and then bind the textbox to the property

**EDIT after comments received** I've not tested this and there might be minor errors but this way you can return a different type depending on the converterparameter

```
 public bool PasswordValidation
    {
        get
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == textBox2.Text)
                return true;
            else
                return
                    false;
        }
    }
```

Value Converters:

```
    public class ValConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == "")
        {
            if ((value as bool?) ?? false)
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            else
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (parameter == "")
        {
            if ((value as bool?) ?? false)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (parameter == "Visibility")
        {
            if ((System.Windows.Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else if (parameter == "Brush")
        {
            if (((SolidColorBrush)value).Color == Colors.Black)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vis:ValConverter x:Key="valConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBox Name="textBox1"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox2" BorderBrush="{Binding ConfirmBorder,Converter={StaticResource valConverter},ConverterParameter=Brush}" />
<TextBlock Text="Passwords Does not Match!" BorderBrush="{Binding ConfirmBorder,Converter={StaticResource valConverter},ConverterParameter=Visibility}"/>
```

Comment: I future it can be replaced on special tooltip with message so i can't to do this.

Comment: When it is replaced with a tooltip then you can just change it to return a boolean indicating the tooltips visibility instead of a border? The other alternative is to use an IValueConverter that will return true when the brush is red and false if the brush is blue or alternatively return a boolean and use an IValueConverter to convert the brush? It will be faster to create 2 seperate properties or just change the property though

Comment: I want to use it as component. Just bind component on two passwordBoxes and all works. Your solution is hard to extend and reuse. I have 3 places where it needs.

Comment: Is it the same as what you had before you asked the question if so then giving a bit more detail in the question would have saved me a lot of time

Comment: Sorry, but I need in more flexible solution.